# "Earth" in Tanach

Tags: words

I am embarrassed to admit, I don't actually know the proper name for the planet we live on in Lashon HaKodesh, or if there even is one.

Maybe it is Ha'Aretz, which literally means "the land". Maybe it is Ha'Olam, "the world/universe".

I don't know. Is there a definite answer to my question? If not, why not? If not Lashon HaKodesh, what about Lashon Chazal?

Comment: From the Torah i.e. also raw tangible perspective Earth (Eretz, Chaled, Tevel, Adamah ..) is not a planet which is from the Gr. root planasthai "to wander" so that's literally כוכבי לכת which are the planets lit. "wandering luminaries" that wander thru the mazalot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ramban on [Bereishis 1:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.1.1.4?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi) calls it "עיגול הארץ".

Meanwhile the [Sefer HaChinuch](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh%2C_Author%27s_Introduction.3?ven=Sefer_HaChinukh,_translated_by_R._Francis_Nataf,_Sefaria_2018&lang=bi) takes a similar approach calling planet Earth - "כדור הארץ". The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Job.38.8.1?ven=Malbim%27s_Job,_trans._Jeremy_I._Pfeffer._Ktav,_2003&lang=bi) on Iyov 38:8 employs the same term.

Comment: In Modern Hebrew, the term used is also כדור הארץ

Comment: What about Tevel?

Comment: @Shalom that's def a good shout! - e.g. לְדָוִד מִזְמוֹר לַה' הָאָרֶץ וּמְלוֹאָהּ תֵּבֵל וְיֹשְׁבֵי בָהּ
 Is it used though in a planetary sense?

Comment: @Shalom it would seem from the meforshim there that it is not the earth as a whole. Rashi says that הָאָרֶץ there is a reference to Eretz Yisroel whereas תֵּבֵל is שאר ארצות

Comment: The Malbim there says that הָאָרֶץ is actually a reference to Planet Earth whereas תֵּבֵל is just the portion of the earth that is inhabited.

Comment: Similarly see the Radak there.

Comment: That's not LHK and is Rambam lashon Chazal here  I'm asking tell me. Who told them to use lashon of a ball or circle or did they get that from late philosophers

Comment: Otoh there's an older term קב הירוק "the green line/circle that encompasses the earth check it out .. but it might allude to the Tzaddik or Qab haEmzai center pillar bc his it's color is green

Answer (score 0):

Copied from my comment above: I'd say earth is not a "planet" etymologically because that's from the Gr. root *planasthai* "to wander" so that's literally כוכבי לכת which are the planets lit. "wandering luminaries" that wander thru the Mazalot.

In Lashon haKodesh/Chazal it looks like we have the top, surface name where we live is "**Tevel**." Alternately it's all seven of the below-mentioned seven names according to another opinion.

Here are some references:

Zohar Bereishit-2

daf 39b

Rabbi Abba says: The Alma Ilaah/Supernal World (Binah) is concealed up, and all its Milui/what's in it are concealed, because it exists in the Supernal secret, the day that includes all days (the height of all heights) [three upper Sefirot]...

Another thing: W'ET HARZ - is as we said, to add the Lower world, for it is made of several compartments (lights), everything resembling what's above. So this is (what's meant by) WHARZ HYTH THU WBHU WHSK WRUaCH [from THU to WRUaCh is four names plus three Waw = 7] - these are the comparts of the earth: (First, bottom) **Eretz (earth), Adamah (soil), Gey (valley), Neshiyah (oblivion), Tziyyah (dryness), Arka (??), and (seventh) Tevel**. The largest (most important, outermost) is **Tevel**, as it's written (Ps. 9:9), "And He will judge Tevel in righteousness.

daf 40a

Rabbi Yossi asked, "What is Tziyyah?"

He replied, That's where Gehenom-hell is, as it says "Tziyyah and Talmawwet." (Another thing: as it's wrtitten) (in the word) WHSK AL-PNY-THUM - this is the secret of the location of genehom. This is Tziyyah, the place of the angel of death, like we said he darkens the face of creation, and this is the place of the Upper HSK-darkness.

THU is Neshiyah, that's totally invisibile, so much that it's NSY-lifted away from everybody, that's why it's called Neshiyyah.

UBHU is Arka, a place that's not "lifted away."

Rabbi Chiyya says no, that would be Gey. WRUH ELKYM MRHFT - this corresponds to Tevel, which is fed by RUH ELKYM. [cf. yBLh - vegetation]. But they're all as one.

The Upper ARZ-earth has it like this too; they're seven compartments up there, layer over layer. All of them are the compartments/dwelling places of supernal angels, these ones above the others. It's the same way down below. They all clong to one another, so that they can be one. They are seven compartments above, and that Upper Aretz unites them, and they all reside inside her. Now all of them perform the praises of the Holy Blessed One, but their levels differ from one another's, and their locations differ one from another.

[Now he describes the seven compartments: First below, place of darkness and stormy angels ... up to seventh and highest, where there's none but the souls of the Tzaddikim]

---

Tikkunei Zohar #32, daf 76b:

And they are the Mazal/constellation Lion, Mazal Bull, and Mazal Eagle, of which it says (Job. 32:29), "Yea all these doth E"L do, three times for a man." "But if these three he will not do for her.." (Ex. 21:11) - for [his] Nefesh in these three reincarnations, to provide her food, clothing and visits - "... then she will leave for nothing, no KSP/hope." "And for three transgressions of Yisrael then for four I will not bring him back (Amos 2:1). So for the fourth which is Mazal Adam "I will not bring him back" - lest he ruin it.

וְאִינוּן מַזָּל אַרְיֵה מַזָּל שׁוֹר מַזָּל נֶשֶׁר, דַּעֲלַיְיהוּ אִתְּמַר (איוב לג, כט) הֶן כָּל אֵלֶּה יִפְעַל אֵ"ל פַּעֲמַיִם שָׁלֹשׁ עִם גָּבֶר, וְאִם שְׁלָשׁ אֵלֶּה לֹא יַעֲשֶׂה לָהּ (שמות כא, יא) לְנַפְשָׁא בִּתְלַת גִּלְגּוּלִין, דְּעָבִיד לָהּ שְׁאֵר כְּסוּת וְעוֹנָה, וְיָצְאָה חִנָּם אֵין כָּסֶף (איוב לג, כט), וְעַל שְׁלֹשָׁה פִּשְׁעִי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְעַל אַרְבָּעָה לֹא אֲשִׁיבֶנּוּ (עמוס ב, א), וְעַל אַרְבָּעָה דְאִיהוּ מַזָּל אָדָם לֹא אֲשִׁיבֶנּוּ, דְּלָא יְקַלְקְלוּ לֵיהּ.

But for the Tzaddikim and (Ex. 20:5) "those that do kindness for the ALPIM/thousands/bosses" - APLIM precisely, three reincarnations, in them is the span of three ALPIM [parsaot?] which are the worlds of KSUPIM/Hope. For whom? "For they that love Him and keep His commandments." (Ex. 20:6). For the wicked who are those that do not turn around in Teshuvah in these three reincarnations, it's said of them (Lev. 23:21), "And I will destroy that soul from amid its people." Rabbi said, "If so I'm going down!" But rather, there are seven earths, constituting seventy, corresponding to the seventy souls [of Yisrael]. Seven earths, they are: **Eretz Adamah Arka Gey Tziyyah Neshiyyah Tevel** - and they are the seven compartments of Gehenom/hell! That Nefesh that doesn't return in Teshuvah in these three [incarnations], the Holy Blessed One sends him down in these three compartments of hell, and that's where he stays forgotten from era to era.

אֲבָל לְצַדִּיקַיָּא וְעֹשֶׂה חֶסֶד לַאֲלָפִים (שמות כ, ה), אֲלָפִים וַדַּאי, תְּלַת גִּלְגּוּלִין בְּהוֹן אִיהוּ רָוַוח תְּלַת אַלְפִּין דְּאִינוּן עָלְמִין דִּכְסוּפִין, וּלְמָאן לְאֹהֲבָיו וּלְשֹׁמְרֵי מִצְוֹתָיו (שמות כ, ו), לְחַיָּיבַיָּא דְּאִינְהוּ לָא יַחְזְרוּן בִּתְיוּבְתָּא בִּתְלַת גִּלְגּוּלִין אִלֵּין, אִתְּמַר בְּהוֹן (ויקרא כג, לא) וְהַאֲבַדְתִּי אֶת הַנֶּפֶשׁ הַהִיא מִקֶּרֶב עַמָּהּ, אָמַר רַבִּי אִם כֵּן אָנָה נָחִית, אֶלָּא שֶׁבַע אַרְעִין אִינוּן, וְסָלְקִין לְשַׁבְעִין לָקֳבֵל שִׁבְעִים נֶפֶשׁ, וְשֶׁבַע אַרְעִין אִינוּן אֶרֶץ אֲדָמָה אַרְקָא גֵּיא צִיָּה נְשִׁיָּה תֵּבֵל, וְאִינוּן שֶׁבַע מְדוֹרִין דְּגֵיהִנָּם, הַהִיא נַפְשָׁא דְלָא חָזְרָה בִּתְיוּבְתָּא בְּאִלֵּין תְּלַת, נָחִית לָהּ קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא בְּמָדוֹרִין דְּגֵיהִנָּם אִלֵּין, וְתַמָּן אִתְנַשֵּׁי לְדָרֵי דָרִין.

But if he's a Tzaddik it's said of him (Prov. 24:16), "Yea, seven times He brings down a Tzaddik, and he gets up." Rabbi Elazar said to him, "But if he's a Tzaddik why does he go down there? Rather, because in order to take out from there every single Nefesh, person, that has a though of Teshuvah but died young in years - so he toils for it. This is the first utterence, which is BRASYT.

וְאִם הוּא צַדִּיק אִתְּמַר בֵּיהּ (משלי כד, טז) כִּי שֶׁבַע יִפּוֹל צַדִּיק וָקָם, אָמַר לֵיהּ רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר, וְאִם הוּא צַדִּיק אַמַּאי נָחִית תַּמָּן, אֶלָּא בְּגִין לְאַפָּקָא מִתַּמָּן כָּל נַפְשָׁא וְנַפְשָׁא מֵאִלֵּין דְּהִרְהֲרוּ בִתְיוּבְתָּא וּמֵתוּ בְקַצְרוּת שְׁנִין, וְאִיהוּ טָרַח בְּגִינֵיהּ, דָּא אִיהוּ מַאֲמַר קַדְמָאָה דְאִיהוּ בְרֵאשִׁית.

---

Here are search results to find many more mentions in the holy T. Zohar and Zohar.

https://he.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93:%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9&limit=50&offset=0&ns0=1&ns106=1&ns108=1&ns110=1&ns112=1&search=%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8+%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%9C+%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5

---

That there are seven earths is also in S. Yetzirah 4:4 but the name's aren't written.

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%22%D7%A7_%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94#%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%93

(ד) שבע כפולות בג"ד כפר"ת, חקק"ן חצב"ן צרפ"ן שקל"ן והמיר"ן וצר בהן ככבים בעול"ם וימים בשנ"ה ושערים בנפ"ש, ומהן חקק שבעה רקיעים **ושבע ארצות** ושבע שבתות, ולפיכך חיבב השביעי תחת השמים: